# show and hide contents with mouse click or mousehover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button and positioned it on top of the browser. So I need to display a dropdown list when mouse click or mouseover on this positioned button.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="translator">
    <div class="translate-btn">Translator</div>
    <div class="translate-dropdown">
      <select>
        <option>Translate-1</option>
        <option>Translate-2</option>
        <option>Translate-3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.translator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.translate-btn {
  background-color: rgba(136, 121, 91, 0.8);
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Using this HTML I need to display "translate-dropdown" DIV when user click or mouseover on "translate-btn".

Can anybody tell me is it possible with pure CSS or do I need to use jquery for this?

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: You can do it pure css, but you need to use html elements that support the events you are looking for (focus and hover). https://jsbin.com/rafemipive/edit?html,css,output  In short use a button instead of a div and you can do it with pure css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using just CSS:

```
.translate-dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.translator:hover .translate-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

Full working example:

```css
.translator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.translate-btn {
  background-color: rgba(136, 121, 91, 0.8);
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}

.translate-dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.translator:hover .translate-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="translator">
    <div class="translate-btn">Translator</div>
    <div class="translate-dropdown">
      <select>
        <option>Translate-1</option>
        <option>Translate-2</option>
        <option>Translate-3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to display the menu on both events (hover and click ) not just hover. I may be wrong though

Comment: Yes, but in order to click on something, you must hover over it first.

Comment: I mean like a toggle drop down. Click to display, move mouse away and drop down is still present, click outside of element to hide drop down. Like this https://jsbin.com/rafemipive/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Well the OP didn't really specify such behavior (whether if the dropdown should stay visible after moving the mouse away, or not). The answer I provided is just the easiest way to achieve what was asked for, using pure CSS, and nothing more.

Comment: If the dropdown needs to stay visible after moving the mouse away, then it probably can't be achieved using just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS has limitations for this kind of task. Here is a javascript approach using jQuery (As I am not a CSS developper):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $target = $('.translate-dropdown');
        $('div.translate-btn').on({ 
                    mouseenter: function(e){
                        $target.css('visibility', 'hidden');     
                    },
                    mouseleave:function(e){
                        $target.css('visibility', 'visible');  
                    },
                   click:function(e){

                   $target.css('visibility', 'visible');
// here you can toggle a class name to track the state of the div and based on the state hide or show it. 

                    }
                });
        }
```

You can use jQuery [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of `.css()` but these will set the CSS `display: none` which is not always the goal of hiding elements.